# Calling React View from Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I can't find a good bare minimum example where I can wire up an express.js route to call a react view.

So far this is what I have.

```
+-- app.js
+-- config
|   +-- server.js
+-- routes
|   +-- index.js
+-- views
|   +-- index.html
```

**app.js**

```
require('./config/server.js');
require('./routes/index.js');
```

config | **server.js**

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),

routes = require('./routes');

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ); // how do I tell express that JSX is my template view engine?

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


var server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Accepting connections on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

routes | **index.js**

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    // how do we call the route that will run index.html ?
    request.render('index');
});
```

views | **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="build/noEpisodes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="noEpisodesMessage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then my index.htm page as well as generated jsx.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## 2021 edit:

the modern solution is to use the [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) tool, followed by dropping in your code where needed. It's been set up to do the rest for you. The React landscape has changed a fair bit over the last six years.

## original 2015 answer:

The usual thing is to use [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router#whats-it-look-like) to take care of the routes; write your React app as a single React app (i.e. all your JSX source ends up bundled into a single app.js file, which knows how to load all your "pages" or "views") and then use express (or Hapi, or any other server process) mostly as your API and asset server, not your page/view generator.

You can then tap into the routes you set up in the `react-router` Router object so that on the express side you can forward your users to the URL that `react-router` can deal with for content loading, so you get

1. user request site.com/lol/monkeys
2. express redirects to /#/lol/monkeys
3. your react app loads the correct view because of the routes in Router
4. optionally, your app does a history.replaceState so that the user sees site.com/lol/monkeys (there are some react-router tricks to do this for you)

You can also automate most of this through server-side-rendering but the name can be confusing: you *still* write your React app as if there is no server involved at all, and then rely on React's render mechanism to fully render individual "pages" for a requested URL which will show all the right initial content while *also* then loading your app and silently hooking it back into the content the user is looking at, so that any interactions past the initial page load are handled by React again, and subsequent navigation is "fake" navigation (your url bar will show a new URL but no actual network navigation will happen, React simply swaps content in/out).

A good example for this is https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example

Comment: What do you mean write the react app in a single react app and bundles of jsx include in the app.js file?

Comment: express isn't a page viewer / generate anyway so not understanding that point above, please explain again thanks.  I mean well it's got the render() method.  So you say don't use that and to use the react-router as it's got render capability

Comment: so if you're not gonna use express as the page/view generator which I assume means I wouldn't then set the app.engine for express, what renders the views?

Comment: React, running in the browser, does your views (unless you wrote your app as an isomorphic application, then express can serve them). This is a "very long answer" for which excellent tutorials already exist on the web, so I would recommending finding those. Give http://jlongster.com/Presenting-The-Most-Over-Engineered-Blog-Ever a read-over, for instance.

Comment: you don't get my question then.  I'm asking about the app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ) what should this be for React?  how do I set the view engine

Comment: the view engine stays plain old HTML if you want to use that, but you could just stick your index.html in an `express.static` instead and not even bother with the view engine. As for the hating of sites with stytling you can totally control yourself: just change the styling. Plenty of "reader mode" extensions/addons for your browser of choice, and there's always dev tools + "change CSS to use normal font sizes". Hardly something worth working up hate for.

Comment: ah so you just use react's view engine to serve up the pages from express's routing...

Comment: On a technical note, React "is" the view engine (there are strictly speaking no views in React, each component, much like an HTML component, is a full MVC in its own right), but: yes

Comment: thanks Mike.  so if React is the view engine, in ExpressJS route, what would you put?   The incoming request comes in and then what?  Because the react jsx lives in a .js file so what else would there be to do, how would I take that request and wire it up to hit the index.html + jsx?  like I mean what would you put in for app.get?  I guess I need to install react-router :)

Comment: I'd put my react code (once bundles) in an `express.static` dir, A full answer does not fit in a comment but, http://pomax.github.io/1420592591221/-taking-react-to-the-next-level-mixins-gulp-and-browserify might be a starting point.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers work with the usual way to use react, to replace an element in the dom like so

```
React.render(<APP />, document);
```

but if you want react to be your "template language" in express, you can also use react to render a simple string of html like so

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var markup = React.renderToString(<APP />);  // <-- render the APP here
  res.send(markup);                          // <-- response with the component
});
```

there are a few other things you need to take care of in terms of bundling all the dependencies and working with jsx. this simple minimalist [tutorial](http://yangweilim.com/blog/2014/12/14/moving-react-component-to-server-side/) and this [blog post](http://www.crmarsh.com/react-ssr/) helped me understand the situation better

note that the sample code in the tutorial uses this syntax

```
var markup = React.renderToString(APP());
```

which has been deprecated and will cause an error. to use it you'd have to replace

```
var APP = require('./app');
```

with

```
var APP = React.createFactory(require('./app'));
```

or just render jsx like i did in the first example. to get the tutorial to work i might have also had to use more recent versions of the dependencies in package.json.

once you've got that down a fancier [tutorial](http://dejanglozic.com/tag/react-js/) shows a more powerful way to use react-engine to render react within express

Comment: The "tutorial" link is now broken. Looks like that domain is parked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it simple you can do this for the entry point of your app:

routes | index.js

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){

    // how do we call the route that will run index.html ?
    res.sendfile('../views/index.html');
});
```

React is going to target a specific element on your index.html page in it's render method:

```
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('foo'));
```

So if your javascript is included in index.html and an element with that id is present react is going to inject your Application into that div. From that point onwards you can do all of the routing with react-router OR you can setup different routes in express and handle them like you did index.html

Comment: thanks, I would have thought res.render() but I obviously don't understand that quite yet...

Comment: I'm jus curious how to do it without react-router just to know how native react/express works without any added libraries yet

Comment: what about setting the view engine.  Do I need to do that with jsx and react for expressJS?

Comment: react is going to target a specific element on your index.html page in it's render method ex. `React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('foo'));` so if your javascript is included in index.html and an element with that id is present react is going to inject your Application into that div. From that point onwards you can do all of the routing with react-router OR you can setup different routes in express and handle them like you did index.html

Comment: please update your answer and I'll mark yours as the one that answered my question, your last comment helped immensely.

Comment: But I think that if you use sendFile(...html) you will have to load react and all the library you're using with your react component on the client side, which can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually dealing with React.render you can use a library called react-helper (https://github.com/tswayne/react-helper).  It sets up a div for you, binds your react components to the div, allows you to pass properties to your components server side, and can even handle server-side rendering if you have webpack configured for your node app or are willing to use babel-register (not recommended for prod).